# How to diagnose an electrified refrigerator frame?

Tags: electrical, refrigerator

Recently (or, perhaps, I recently noticed) my garage fridge started shocking me if I touch it in the wrong place. (A sampling of "wrong" places: the door hinge, a spot on the other corner where the paint is worn off)

The shock is quite severe, definitely not a static discharge.

I bought an outlet tester, which tells me that the outlet that the refrigerator is   plugged into has an open ground.  **Is this enough to make the fridge shock me?**  I have checked for frayed or damaged wires inside the fridge and didn't find anything.

EDIT: More info: The fridge is currently plugged in to a surge protector, which is plugged in to a plug-in type GFCI, which is plugged into the ungrounded outlet.

EDIT 2: I have since fixed this problem by grounding the outlet in question.  I don't know whether this masks a legitimate problem with the refrigerator, or if this was the actual solution, but the bottom line is that it not longer shocks me when I touch it.  Thank you everyone for all of your help!

Comment: Use a multimeter to do a continuity test between the ungrounded (hot) conductor and the equipment ground conductor, this will confirm a ground fault.  Unplug the fridge, set the multimeter to test continuity, touch one probe to the "hot" blade on the plug, and the other to the ground pin.  If you hear a beep or get a reading, you have a fault. Repeat the test for the "neutral" and ground, in a modern fridge with a 3 wire cord neutral and ground should not be bonded in the fridge.  Have the fridge serviced to repair the fault, before plugging the fridge back in.

Comment: Keep in mind, if the equipment ground was not faulty you may not get shocked, but there is still a fault in the fridge that must be fixed.

Comment: @Tester101 this and your comment below are well worth being posted as an answer.

Comment: @Tester101 Agree with BMitch. Thank you for providing some actual diagnostics that I can perform.

Comment: @Tester101 I performed this test.  Neither Neutral-Ground nor Hot-Ground were bonded.  Hot-Neutral was. (as you would expect, right?)

Comment: Hot and neutral may or may not test positive for continuity, and it would be less likely for them to be connected if the device is unplugged.  When the compressor is running they might test positive (DO NOT run this test while it's running), but other than that there should be a relay or switch that turns the compressor on/off.  To know for sure, you'd have to find a wiring diagram (sometimes there is one folded up somewhere inside the cabinet).

Comment: This comment relates to the hot-neutral continuity of the refrigerator's plug, right?  With one lead of my multimeter on each of the two flat prongs on the fridge's plug, it tests positive for continuity.

Comment: I just found a generic fridge schematic, and it looks like hot neutral should not be connected when the fridge is off (at least from what I could tell).  There will be a switch for lights, one in the ice maker (if you have an ice maker), and a temperature control switch that isolates the defrost heater (if you have one), freezer fan, condenser fan, and the compressor.  So unless you open the door, you probably should not be testing positive for continuity.

Comment: The next step I would take is to check each outlet (outlet in this case is any break in the wire that feeds a device, not just receptacles), and make sure neutral and ground are not physically bonded.  Neutral and ground should only be bonded in the main service panel. Sometimes people connect a fixtures ground to neutral (to trick their receptacle tester into giving the OK), which *can* lead to current on the equipment ground.

Comment: You could also check for continuity between hot and neutral to the fridges case. Only ground should be bonded to the frame.

Comment: @Tester101 Here is the actual wiring diagram from the fridge, fyi: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/853/fridgewiringdiagram.jpg/

Comment: So it looks like there is an indicator light (or other device labeled "power on" in the schematic), which is always on when the fridge is plugged in. Is this correct?  if so, neutral and hot would be connected through that light so you probably would read continuity between hot-neutral.

Comment: I performed the continuity test between the plug and frame.  Ground is connected, neither hot nor neutral are connected.  Regarding your previous advice to check for neutrals bonded to grounds:  Does this advice apply, despite the fact that the ground plug is not wired in the receptacle at all? i.e. no wire is connected to the ground screw of the receptacle. (Sorry if I'm mangling terms)

Comment: No indicator light, but I suspect that the power-on device is the timer for self-defrost.  There is a device with a knob that acts like a timer on back/bottom of the fridge.  (I keep calling it a fridge, but as I mentioned elsewhere, this is a converted freezer -- converted by turning the coarse-adjustment screw on the thermostat.)

Comment: Hmm. So the fault must be in the device itself...  It's odd you would see this problem with two different devices. Do you only get shocked when the compressor of fans are running?

Comment: A flash of insight: The fridge is plugged into the same power strip (which is, itself connected to a plug-in type GFCI) as my pool equipment (Intex pool).  Could the fault lie with the pool equipment, electrifying that whole "ground" circuit?

Comment: Also, is there a better way to test whether I've fixed the problem than briefly shocking myself? :)

Comment: So there is a multi-receptacle device with both the fridge and pool equipment plugged in?  Then yes, the fault could be in the pool equipment and/or the multi-receptacle device.

Comment: Yes you should be able to read a voltage on the case, if you measure to true ground.  Or you could set the multimeter to measure 200VAC touch one probe to the case, and the other to your finger.  This will tell you if there is a potential difference between you and the case.

Comment: Electricity is like water, it will always find the path of least resistance (even when that path is through you). If the ground in the multi-receptacle device is carrying current; and it can't return via the disconnected equipment ground, it could return through the fridge case.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4195/discussion-between-dustin-rasener-and-tester101)

Answer (score 8):

An open ground is not in and of itself a problem.  Grounds are there to dump excess voltage in case something goes wrong. If all our appliances worked properly all the time, there'd be no need for ground.

So what you have is two problems:

1. Your fridge has a bare wire rubbing against the frame or other electrical short,
2. And, the safety device meant to mitigate such a fault (ground) is broken.

If I were you, I'd replace the outlet, preferably with a GFI, and make sure the ground is attached.  Then I'd have someone in to look at the fridge.

Comment: I have inspected the fridge in all the places I have easy access to (which includes a panel inside the unit itself), and all of the wires and insulation look pristine.  Is there a failure besides "bare wire touching frame" that could cause the frame to become electrified?

Comment: The leak to ground can occur anywhere a power conductor is in close proximity to a grounding conductor. Could simply be too much solder on a printed circuit board, or insulation failure inside an electric motor, or anywhere else there is insulation isolating power from a supporting bracket or such, where the insulation has broken down. Can be very hard to isolate. You do need to fix the outlet as well, but if you install a GFI with the current fridge configuration, the GFI will always trip and the fridge will never run. If you fix the outlet grounding, the shock you experience will be reduced.

Comment: Reducing the shock is not enough.  It needs to be eliminated. Per Cudmore, you **need** to have someone fix the fridge!

Comment: I was once told by an appliance repairman that modern refrigerators have small, low-voltage heaters inside the outside shell that warm the outside in order to prevent condensation. These heaters frequently short circuit. When it happened to me, the fridge didn't shock me, but it tripped the GFCI.

Comment: @ bib. Thx for clarifying. I ran out of chars to say what I should have said. I handled that poorly.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a certified electrician, but I have rich experience dealing with appliances that had similar issues, even two brand new washing machines of a well know European brand would do so. Every time it was solved by grounding the device - if there was wiring with ground wire then it would be connected to that wire and if there was not a ground wire it would be connected to improvised grounding that was likely not up to any code, but anyway each time the problem was just solved.

Comment: +1, other comments have mentioned that the outlet grounding screw is not wired, and this appliance is designed to be plugged into to a grounded outlet. My guess is that the compressor motor is throwing off a good bit of static electricity, not unlike a [Van de Graaff generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_de_Graaff_generator).

Comment: This is my current theory.  The problem was solved by grounding the device.

Comment: Would this answer also answer my current question?:
http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/57801/why-are-all-of-my-appliances-becoming-energized-when-ground-wire-is-excluded/57802?noredirect=1#comment79880_57802

and

http://www.quora.com/Why-are-all-of-my-appliances-becoming-energized-when-ground-wire-is-excluded

Comment: @skybreaker: I'd say "yes", most likely.

Comment: So I guess with modern appliances it is now standard to have some small current flow through the chassis which must be handled by the earth , otherwise the user will feel it?

Comment: @skybreaker: It depends. If the device has "double insulation" accompanied by a square inside a square pictogram somewhere in the spec - then it is guaranteed to work just fine without grounding. Power tools such as drills typically have that. Otherwise you have to ground the appliance to prevent being shocked when touching it. That's not specific to new aplliances - old stuff had to be grounded too but 50 years ago people didn't care about electric safety as much as they do now.

Comment: So you're saying that in the old days they constantly got small shocks from the chassis of every ungrounded metal-frame appliance?

Comment: @skybreaker: That happened a lot and happened to me too. The shock strength greatly depends on other conditions - if you're staying on dry floor with dry slippers on your feet it's almost never strong enough to feel it yet a voltage indicator will light up no problem.

Comment: I must say that I'm very surprised by learning all of this. You live and learn.

Answer (score 1):

You say the fridge is plugged into a power strip and the power strip is then plugged in through a portable GFCI receptacle. If you are getting shocked by the fridge, but the GFCI is not tripping, then **the GFCI is faulty** and not providing you with any protection.

A [plug-in GFCI receptacle tester](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002LZTKIU) has a button to trip the GFCI. I hope the tester you got is this kind; if so, you can use this to confirm your GFCI is busted, but I would just replace it rather than go without protection.

Now, on to the fridge. The tool you want to use here is a multimeter.

(Aside: If you're doing anything with electricity, you should have a multimeter. In a pinch, you can get by with a so-called "neon circuit tester": this has two leads and a light on the body. The light lights up when it detects a high enough voltage traveling across the leads. Be careful; many of these are intended for automobile use and will not survive mains power. I've used a couple, and I like the [Gardner Bender GET-213HV](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000BOHICI), because the leads clip to the body at the right width for a US receptacle and the light is good and bright.)

Plug a 3-prong extension cord into a grounded outlet. Run the cord over by the fridge. Take your multimeter/neon tester and stick the black COM lead into the grounded U-slot on the extension cord. Touch the other lead to one of the places you felt a shock on the fridge. If it reads a voltage difference, congratulations: Your fridge is live and ready to shock the daylights out of you. Unplug the fridge and move your chilled goods elsewhere.

I don't know whether an electrified fridge could be salvaged, or whether you'll have to get a new one. Good luck.

P.S. Those receptacle testers are apparently considered somewhat unreliable. You can follow up by testing everything they test using your multimeter/neon circuit tester. Reversed polarity: one probe in the long slot, one in the ground slot, if you have power, oops. Ground: one probe in the hot slot, one in the ground slot, no power, no ground. (No ground, and you can't really test for reversed polarity, either; use the extension cord trick to get a known good ground.)

There's also always the open up the outlet, pull everything out, and see how it's wired together trick. It takes far more time, but it lets you see directly whether there's a ground screw, whether anything's attached to the ground screw, whether the polarity's reversed, etc. But don't open things up unless you're comfortable putting them back together.

Comment: A GFCI doesn't detect current on the ground, it detects a difference in current between the ground and neutral. You can get shocked via a static charge or an improper ground and have a perfectly functioning GFCI.

Comment: @BMitch GFCI detects a difference in current between hot and neutral, not ground and neutral (current in = current out).

Comment: @Tester101, doh, before my morning caffeine, that's what I meant to say. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @BMitch Doesn't getting shocked via an improper ground mean current is flowing from hot and returning via you, not via neutral? I'd expect the difference in current out via hot and that returning via neutral should be enough to trigger the GFCI if OP is getting shocked.

Comment: @BMitch Ah, just saw your guess about static electricity. If that's so, then yes, the GFCI is not at fault. But testing with a multimeter should reveal that: you'd see voltage on contact that dissipates right afterwards, rather than the steady voltage you'd see with a ground fault.

Comment: Precisely, it depends on the type of shock. This isn't easy to diagnose with so many guesses and answers happening all over the question and comments.

Comment: I haven't been willing to keep my finger on it, but the shock seems to be sustained.  I appreciate the difficulty in diagnosing this over the internet and offer my sincere thanks!

Comment: @DustinRasener I highly recommend getting a multimeter and following the steps in my answer. Then we can all stop guessing. :)

Comment: @JeremyW.Sherman I have done a (similar) test with a multimeter.  Rather than running an extension cord to ground, I used myself as ground (pinching the lead between my fingers and standing on the concrete in bare feet).  The potential difference was ~50v AC.  This was when the compressor was running.  When the compressor was not running, it was ~8v AC (and did not feel shocking to the touch).  Does that help?  I'll get the extension cord if that's not good enough, just out of appreciation for everyone's help. :)

Comment: I am less certain of how to interpret those results. The 42 V difference between when the compressor is running versus not running sounds like you're seeing some of the power drawn by the compressor bleed into the frame.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same situation. Did you notice a reference ground on that schematic? It would explain getting 107Vac on the exterior without the requisite 5ma current that would trip the GFCI. I got bit by my refrigerator last night; it was wet on the concrete and I was barefoot. I read 107Vac anywhere on the exterior. I tied a piece of #12 from my panel ground bus back to the frame and the issue cleared. The house I'm renting has no ground to the receptacles. Had this been a true ground fault, the breaker should have tripped when I provided a low impedance path back to the panel. I'm glad for the sake of my family that I AM a certified general electrician!

Answer (score 0):

How old is the refrigerator?

If the ref. is really old you might think about replacing it with a more energy efficient one or just get rid of it if it's not used much. Some utilities have rebates for old working refrigerators. An old ref. can cost a lot to operate.

Comment: It's 2004.  I actually just bought it used.  Also, technically it's an upright freezer.  I've turned the coarse-adjustment screw on the thermostat to operate it at fridge temps.  Can you guess what I'm using it for?  This is my kegerator, and it gets used plenty. :)

Comment: By the way, it's funny you should mention the rebate.  When we discovered that my previous kegerator was shocking me (yes, there is more to the story -- do you suppose it's relevant?), we replaced it, thinking that something had gone wrong.  Our electric company gave us $30 to haul it off.

Comment: @DustinRasener if this is the second fridge that has shocked you, open up the receptacle box and make sure the neutral and ground are not bonded in the box.

Comment: I'm with @tester101.  It sounds like there's stray voltage on the ground.

Comment: @Tester101: Thanks.  I did just that, and the ground receptacle is not wired at all.